# How to get count in pivot table that does NOT count duplicate entries

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I am setting up a pivot table, and I would like for it to give me the count of the number of unique combinations of two fields, not just the total count. That is, each combination should only be counted once regardless if there are duplicate records for that combination.

For example, with the raw data below, I would like the pivot table to count 10 (not 12) total records for combinations of teacher and subject. That is, `(Teacher 1, Math)` only gets counted once, and the same for `(Teacher 3, English)`.

```
Teacher 1   Math     Student 1
Teacher 1   Math     Student 2
Teacher 1   English  Student 3
Teacher 1   History  Student 4
Teacher 2   Math     Student 5
Teacher 2   Science  Student 6
Teacher 2   Biology  Student 7
Teacher 3   Math     Student 8
Teacher 3   Science  Student 9
Teacher 3   English  Student 10
Teacher 3   English  Student 11
Teacher 3   Math     Student 12
```

How can I set up my pivot table to do this?

Comment: Thanks David, I really am useless when it comes to excel actually pretty much anything technical

Comment: No, this doesn't make sense to me. Could you give an example of what the data should look like in the pivot table?

Comment: Total Subjects          Total Students

Comment: the pivot table should have Teacher 1, 2 and 3 in the first column and then calculate how many subjects per teacher, so teacher 1 will have 3 subjects as Math is repeated.

Comment: I tried to edit your question but ended up basically rewriting it. I think I got what you're asking for, but if I messed something up, you can rollback the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't directly possible in Excel 2007. If you were on [Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552440/1607446) or [Excel 2010 with the PowerPivot add-in](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2009/12/26/distinct-count-measure-in-powerpivot-using-dax.aspx), you could do it using the new 'Distinct Count' feature.

Siddharth Rout outlined a [good workaround on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11876301/1607446). Add a column to your data, and copy this formula down:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2=A2)*($B$2:$B2=B2))>1,0,1)
```

Then create your pivot based on the 1st and 3rd column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use a concatenate function, add a D column with concatenate(a2,b2) thus creating a unique id for teacher+subject.  Copy the formula down.  Then use that column as your count value.